# install app from xxxlinux64.zip manjaro

Tags: manjaro, software-rec

I need to install an app, betaflight-configurator_10.3.1_linux64.zip, on manjaro os.
I have the most recent version installed via Aur and the software manager but need an old version which i downloaded from git-hub.
I had issues installing apps from git-hub before and hoping to learn something today.
I am just not finding solutions doing web searches.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install unzip if you don't already have it:

`sudo pacman -S unzip`

If you want to unzip the files to your current dir:

`unzip betaflight-configurator_10.3.1_linux64.zip`
If you want to unzip to a specific dir:
`unzip betaflight-configurator_10.3.1_linux64.zip -d ~/thisisanotherpath`

Now, cd to the place where the files are, run ls, and you should see a file without any extensions on the end of it, type a dot and slash and then the name of this file, like so: `./betaflight-configurator`

If you don't want to run it from a terminal everytime and you have a desktop enviroment, there's also a .desktop file in the folder, you can move this to /usr/share/applications/ and this will make the app show up on your desktop/start menu